# Ember data post to Web API

Tags: ember.js, asp.net-web-api, ember-data

How can I get my web api to understand the format returned by ember data?

ember data is sending like this:

```
{client: {firstName:"",lastName:""}}
```

As far as I understand web api is looking for

```
{firstName:"",lastName:""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much googling I finally get the right terms and figured out how to do it. Simple serilizer update on the ember data side:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serializeIntoHash: function (hash, type, record, options) {
    Ember.merge(hash, this.serialize(record, options));
  }
});
```